# Слайдер калькулятор

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать калькулятор выгоды по простой формуле:
[image: ы]Формула расчет прибыли: 2300 * количество заказов * 0,27

Опыта у меня мало, но очень хочу понимать как писать такие простые калькуляторы самостоятельно. з.ы. Вёрстка готова, осталось создать калькулятор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дак как есть так и считать, отлавливать событие изменения вашего бегунка, и посчитать значение по формуле и вписать результат, куда надо.

```js
function calc(tb){
  var v = document.getElementById("val") ;
  var r = document.getElementById("result");
  
  v.innerHTML = tb.value;
  r.innerHTML = tb.value*2300*0.27;
   
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="track"  onchange="calc(this);"/>

<div>Значение <span id="val"></span></div>
<div>Стоимость <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант! Спасибо!

Comment: А как сделать чтобы значения изменялись динамически? (прямо во время прокрутки)